# Калькулятор html + php

Tags: php, html, php7

Изучая php, решил написать простой калькулятор на php.
Имеются два input для двух значений, `select` для выбора математической операции и `submit`.
Вопрос в том, **как используя `select` + `option`, можно отправить значение математического оператора PHP** и в дальнейшем организовать работу калькулятора с показом на отдельной странице (`result.php` к примеру)

html:

```html
<form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first-value">
    <select name="math-op">
        <option value="addition">+</option>
        <option value="subtraction">-</option>
        <option value="multiplication">×</option>
        <option value="division">÷</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="second-value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Посчитать!">
</form>
```

Comment: У вас же есть value выбранного option, в чем проблема?

Comment: в result.php
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грубо, но примерно так:

```
$result = 0;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['math-op'] == 'addition') {
        $result = $_POST['first-value'] + $_POST['second-value'];
    } elseif ($_POST['math-op'] == 'subtraction') {
        $result = $_POST['first-value'] - $_POST['second-value'];
    } elseif ($_POST['math-op'] == 'multiplication') {
        $result = $_POST['first-value'] * $_POST['second-value'];
    } elseif ($_POST['math-op'] == 'division') {
        $result = $_POST['first-value'] / $_POST['second-value'];
    }
    echo $result;
}
```